# Tool or methods for automatically creating contextual links within a large corpus of content?

Tags: seo, nlp

Here's the basic scenario - I have a corpus of say 100,000 newspaper-like articles.  Minimally they will all have a well-defined title, and some amount of body content.

What I want to do is find runs of text in articles that ought to link to other articles.

So, if article Foo has a run of text like "Students in 8th grade are being encouraged to read works by John-Paul Sartre" and article Bar is titled (and about) "The important works of John-Paul Sartre", I'd like to automagically create that HTML link from Foo to Bar within the text of Foo.

Answer (score 2):

You should ask yourself something before adding the links. What benefit for users do you want to achieve by doing this? You probably want to increase the navigability of your site. Maybe it is better to create an easier way to add links to older articles in form used to submit new ones. Maybe it is possible to add a "one click search for selected text" feature. Maybe you can add a wiki-like functionality that lets users propose link for selected text. You probably want to add links to related articles (generated through tagging system or text mining) below the articles.

Some potential problems with fully automated link adder:
You may need to implement a good word sense disambiguation algorithm to avoid confusing or even irritating the user by placing bad automatic links with regex (or simple substring matching).

As the number of articles is large you do not want to generate the html for extra links on every request, cache it instead.

You need to make a decision on duplicate titles or titles that contain other title as substring (either take longest title or link to most recent article or prefer article from same category).

TLDR version: find alternative solutions that provide desired functionality to the users.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are text mining tools.  You can find more info and links at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mining.  You might also want to check out Lucene and its ports at http://lucene.apache.org.  Using these tools, the basic idea would be to find a set of similar articles based on the article (or title) in question.  You could search various properties of the article including titles and content or both.  A tagging system a la Delicious (or Stackoverflow) might also be helpful.  Rather than pre-creating the links between articles, you'd present the relevant articles in an interface much like the Related questions interface on the right-hand side of this page.

If you wanted to find and link specific text in each article, I think you'd need to do some preprocessing to select pertinent phrases to key on.  Even then I think it would be very hard not to miss things due to punctuation/misspellings or to not include irrelevant links for the same reasons.

Comment: Yeah, related articles I understand.  It's the selection of specific text that I'm looking for - I feel like it may be a pretty tough problem.